# php://input data issue in romania encoding in http request from android

Tags: php, android, json, http-post, encode

When I send http request to my webservice it gets this kind of json object through  `file_get_contents('php://input')`

```
{"sessid":"9dfe966775ff8583d115ae29e510b617","restaurant_id":"c?s?tori"}
```

actually I'm sending this :

```
{"sessid":"9dfe966775ff8583d115ae29e510b617","restaurant_id":"căsători"}
```

this input is from romanian key board from mobile: `căsători`.

I'm using http post request, and this is my header.

```
      try {


        String responseText = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(url);

      httppostreq.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppostreq.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        httppostreq.setEntity( new StringEntity(json.toString(),"UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);

        try {
            responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
            System.out.println("response="+responseText);
            json_object = new JSONObject(responseText);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (NullPointerException np) {

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException np) {

    }
```

I need romanian inputs to be parse in API and get proper output.

Comment: How do you know that you get :"c?s?tori" in the php script? What are you doing with it? How do you display it? You have eyes on your server?

Answer (score 0):

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
```

Change that to:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

And change

```
responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
```

to

```
responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi, I change this with UTF-8 and gOT response like below,
here i'm writing my input= outout

căsători = cãsãtori,

**another input**
Aș putea întreba dacă vărului Mulțumesc .ați în să mă ierți român Felicitări pentru logodnă la vărul. M-am întrebat =  A? putea întreba dacã vãrului Mul?umesc .a?i în sã mã ier?i român Felicitãri pentru logodnã la vãrul. M-am întrebat

I'm getting response like this.

Comment: `I'm getting response like this`. In your code you are not getting the response. . So where do you see what? Am i talking bullshit again?

Comment: Hi @greenapps , I'm using netbeans as IDE and created webservice in CI, in logcat I can see response, because I print the response server side, and I can see all this in my logcat. I need to resolve this as soon as possible. 
Even I tried other conversion type also like **iso-8859-2** but didn't get proper output.

Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Just put `echo(file_get_contents('php://input'));` in your php script. (No other lines). You should then get the response/echo on Android side. Add a few codelines to your post (not in a comment) to retrieve the response. After that i will tell you if you did it correct.

Comment: Same way we are doing, that's why I'm giving you both input and output both.

Comment: Same way? You did not add the code to get the response and show it in your android client. Why not? Why do i have to ask this three times?

Comment: `httppostreq.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            httppostreq.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            httppostreq.setEntity( new StringEntity(json.toString(),"UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
   responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
                System.out.println("response="+responseText);
                json_object = new JSONObject(responseText);
           `
This is my client side code, by doing SYSO, I'm able to print response

Comment: I aldo asked you to put it in your post. Not in a comment like you did.

Comment: You removed a lot of code. Why? I only asked you to ADD some code.

Comment: Hey, Both code are same, there is no major difference. in this I used StringEntity as parameter, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Please put the complete code back in your post.starting with DefaultHttpClient.

Comment: Can you help me? How may I able to see your edits? I tried to compare with my code but there is not found any changes.

Comment: ??????????? Just read my answer again. I added something to my answer. In total i suggest two changes with adding "UTF-8" parameter.

Comment: Ya I'm trying, and get back to you..!! with results.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps .!! Thanks a lot.  I tried this from last 3 days, I just forgot to put "UTF-8" in EntityUtils. Thanks again. and Sorry if I made any mistakes while talking to you.